# How to assign an ID to a dynamic dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to assign a session ID (this  will be hidden) whenever the first select dropdown is used. The session ID is the number 300, 301, etc. after the "day".

When a user selects something from the "preferred" dropdown it should assign the "300" value to the "sessionid" dropdown and simultaneously change the value of the "day" dropdown (which works already btw)

How do I do implement it properly?

Please see code below:

```
<select id="preferred" class="preferred" name="preferred">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Mountain Dew">Mountain Dew</option>
  <option value="Seven Up">Seven Up</option>
</select>
<select id="day" class="day" name="day">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select id="sessionid" class="sessionid" name="sessionid">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

$(function() {
  var selectValues = {
   "Mountain Dew": {
   "Monday": "300"
  },
   "Seven Up": {
   "Tuesday": "301"
  }
};

var $preferred = $('select.preferred');
var $day = $('select.day');
var $sessionid = $('select.sessionid');

$preferred.change(function() {
  $day.empty().append(function() {
   var output = '';
   $.each(selectValues[$preferred.val()], function(key, value) {
   output += '<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>';
  });
  return output;
  });
 }).change();
});
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/creativemix/5ZWrE/2/

Comment: You can use `Element.id = 'id'` to set an id in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id

Comment: Why not just use a hidden text field and set the `id` or `value` of that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to set the value of session id dropdown. Include this after setting the output variable in your fiddle.

```
$sessionid.empty()
     .append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value",value)
     .text(value));
```

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZWrE/4/) to the fiddle.

But, as others already suggested, why not use a hidden text field to store the value?

To store the value in a hidden field,

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSessionId" />
```

And add this to the script.

```
$('#hdnSessionId').val(value);
```

Comment: Wow! It works! I like your suggestion on storing it on a text field instead. If I were to use a text field, what changes to the code should be made? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a input of type hidden and set the value. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really helped me a lot! More power to you. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.id = 'id'` to set an id in javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id

In your code that would probably be something like this at the point where you want to assign the id:

```
$sessionid[0].id = $day.val();
```

But please note an id must start with a letter and numbers are generally bad practice even if it does work.

Putting the value you need in a hidden field is probably preferable over this solution.